# InitWithCoder, [super init] or [super initWithCoder]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can I ask which version I should be using, in my older apps I seem to be using "B" but when I look at a lot of examples online I am seeing a lot of versions that look like "A".

```
// A
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self=[super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if(self) {
        ...
```

OR

```
// B
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self=[super init];
    if(self) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the superclass adopts `NSCoding` (which is likely albeit not always the case), always call

```
[super initWithCoder:decoder]
```

Otherwise call its designated initializer.

Comment: Ah I see, the superclass is NSObject (which from what I can tell does not conform to NSCoding) so in this case I should use "B". Much appreciated, a very clear / concise answer.

Comment: NSObject is don't like init withCoder,aha:)

Answer (score 13):

Depends on whether the superclass conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol or not. If it does, you must call `[super initWithCoder:decoder]`. If it does not, you must call the superclass' designated initializer.

For example, if your class is a direct subclass of `NSObject`, you would call `[super init]`, `NSObject`'s designated initializer, since `NSObject` does not conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: Can I ask, if a class conforms to NSCoding does initWithCoder become its designated initialiser?

Comment: No, the designated initializer remains the same.

Comment: The Xcode 4 boilerplate for initWithCoder uses [super initWithCoder] regardless of whether the superclass conforms to NSCoding -- took a little while to figure out where it was blowing up.